# Past indefinite or past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

> Yesterday I read the book you gave me. (You gave me the book yesterday, too.)

Is it correct? And what would change in the meaning of the whole sentence if the verb "give" took the form "had given"?

Comment: What do you think would change?

Comment: I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: When you translate the sentences into your first language, is there a difference between them?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I don't think Past Perfect ***had given*** implies anything in particular as regards whether the book was given yesterday or earlier. Come to that, it would be entirely a stylistic choice whether to use PP even if the context were *...the book you **gave/had given** me last Christmas*. In general, as a learner it would probably be best if you stuck with Simple Past wherever it's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Yeah, and you'd prefer the simpler form in your first language as well, because there's no ambiguity, since you first have to be given a book in order to read it. Use the past perfect only when it makes a difference, when the sentence could be misinterpreted otherwise. The past perfect is commonly used with *when*; for instance (I'm very unimaginative): "When he came here he found an extremely rare coin." vs. "When he came here he'd found an extremely rare coin." See how the past perfect makes a difference there? The past perfect is also used in reporting and in past unreal conditionals, e.g.